# Finding all the indexes of some elements on a given list. Can it be done in less than O(n^2) without arrays in Haskell?

Tags: arrays, list, haskell, array-algorithms

Given 2 lists of unique, orderable, non-contiguous elements, say:

```
['d', 'a', 'z', 'b']
```

I want to find their index in another list, say:

```
['a', 'b', 'z', 'd']
```

The result would be a list with their positions:

```
[3, 0, 2, 1]  -- element at 0 is at 3,
              -- element at 1 is at 0, etc.
```

Comment: Is the second list guaranteed to be a rearrangement of the first?

Comment: Theory predicts that without arrays, functional programming is at most O(log n) times slower. Indeed, you can replace an array with a tree map having O(log n) access instead of O(1). So, if you can spot a O(f(n)) algorithm in the imperative world, you know that you can achieve O(f(n) log f(n)) in the functional world. Whether this gap can be closed is still an open problem, AFAIK. (In practice, many functional languages support arrays directly so to avoid the issue)

Comment: @chi Where could I read up on that theory (or, under which names should I search)?

Comment: @phg I'm not an expert in this topic, but [pure vs impure lisp](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall03/cs528/handouts/Pure%20Versus%20Impure%20LISP.pdf) seems to be a good starting reference (Okasaki mentions it in his book, together with Ben-Amran & Galil).

Comment: @dfeuer yes, maybe "some elements" wasn't the best wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be also done in `O(n log n)` time with a couple of sorts. I assume that the second list is a permutation of the first one.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import Data.Function

correspIx :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [(Int, Int)]
correspIx = zip `on` map fst . sortBy (comparing snd) . zip [0..]
```

`correspIx` returns a list of pairs with the indices corresponding to each other:

```
correspIx "dazb" "abzd" == [(1,0),(3,1),(0,3),(2,2)]
```

We need another sort to get the result indicated in the question:

```
correspIx' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [Int]
correspIx' xs ys = map snd $ sortBy (comparing fst) $ correspIx xs ys
```

Now `correspIx' "dazb" "abzd" == [3,0,2,1]`.

Comment: I think this answer is more functional since it doesn't use Hash tables, which use an array under the hood, I believe.

Comment: @LayGonzález, that kind of depends on how strictly you interpret "hash table". In Haskell, a `HashMap` is represented as a trie.

Answer (score 6):

One simple solution is to create a Data.Map or hash table using the second list so you can have O(log n) index lookups instead of O(n) ones.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to create a map of all the characters in the destination array and then you have two options:

You can use [merge sort](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)  sort the list in `O(n log n)` time, and if the array of tokens you are looking for is in constant length, you will do a constant number of searches in `O(log n)`.

Another solutions is to take the destination array and put it all in a hash map, and then search there.